# Cannot flash esp32

Tags: mingw, gnu, esp32

when I try use **make flash** esp32 I got some problem. what is the error? how i solve it? thanks all. My error here:

```
File "C:/msys32_out2/mingw32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '/??/COM12': WindowsError(123, 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.')
make: *** [/c/msys32/home/tuant/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/Makefile.projbuild:55: flash] Error 1
```

Comment: Not sure where that `/??/COM12` stuff comes from, but Windows COM ports numbered 10 or higher need special addressing,see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/115831/howto-specify-serial-ports-larger-than-com9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you got in your Serial Flasher Config for the serial port?  Make sure you erase anything that's there and have only COM12.  My guess is you have slashes left over from what the default is.